# Как сдвинуть масссив не POD типов без new[]?

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы, malloc, конструктор-копирования, new

У меня возникла проблема: нужно сдвинуть обычный динамический массив объектов (с нетривиальными конструкторами копирования и перегруженным оператором =). Например, на 1 позицию вправо. Как сделать это **без** перераспределения памяти (т.е. без `new[]` или `malloc`)?

P.S. Деструктор тоже нетривиальный.

```
struct myobject;

myobject* first_created_obj = nullptr;

struct myobject {
    myobject() {
        if (!first_created_obj) first_created_obj = this;
    }
    myobject(myobject& obj) {
        if (first_created_obj == &obj) first_created_obj = this;
    }
};

myobject first;
myobject second;

int main() {
    myobject* arr = malloc(sizeof(myobject) * 10);
    new (arr) myobject(first);
    new (arr + 1) myobject(second);

    // далее нужно сделать сдвиг так,чтобы не было malloc и при этом
    // first_created_obj указывал на тот самый первый созданный объект,
    // при этом сдвинутый

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Без new[] вы обойтись можете, если память под массив выделена с запасом. Обязательно придётся вызвать placement new для нового элемента, оператор присваивания для всех элементов и деструктор (без delete) для элемента, который удаляется. Оператор присваивания можно заменить на конструктор копирования/перемещания внутри placement new и вызвов деструктора.

Comment: т.е. по пунктам можно пожалуйста?) Сначала приравниваем предыдущий объект к  следующему, потом вызывваем деструктор этого предыдущего, все в циклом, а потом placement new на освободившееся место? Или как?

Comment: Или placement new с коструктором копирования на последний элемент, затем присваивания с конца к началу, в конце деструктор на бывшем первом элементе.

Comment: Или placement new на элементе в конце, деструктор на предыдущем. И так далее в цикле. Цикл тоже с конца к началу.

Comment: Если места для сдвига достаточно, и в тех позициях, куда сдвигаем, сконструированы объекты подходящего типа, то просто вызываем `std::move_backward` / `std::move`. Если вы просто выделили «сырую память» и ней вручную конструируете объекты , то тогда придётся возиться как предлагает StanislavVolodarskiy. В общем, нужен минимальный пример кода, как создаётся подвергаемый сдвигу массив.

Comment: @wololo ок,сделал пример того, что имел в виду)

Comment: Присвоение сырой памяти без placement new - undefined behaviour.

Comment: ой, пофиксил UB)

Comment: @wololo а как работает std move и как в нем решается проблема "съехавших" указателей из-за перемещения?

Comment: @SupremeMachine, проблему съехавших указателей будет решать написанный вами оператор присвоения для вашего класса. А `std::move_backward` просто будет его вызывать)

Comment: @wololo , `std::move_backward` использует арифметику указателей. Как я могу подсунуть указатель на нужный тип без UB (сами объекты выделены в буфере `unsigned char[]`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предположим у нас есть буфер на четыре объекта, в котором созданы три из них. Задача переместить эти объекты на одну позицию вправо. Лямбда `array` обеспечивает доступ к объектам выделенным в буфере:

```
const int n = 4;
alignas(object_t) unsigned char buffer[sizeof(object_t) * n];
auto array = [&buffer](int i) -> object_t & {
    return *reinterpret_cast<object_t *>(buffer + (sizeof(object_t) * (i)));
};

for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
    new(&array(i)) object_t(i);
}
```

То что у меня буфер - локальный массив на суть задачи не влияет. То же самое делается в динамической памяти.

### Перемещающий конструктор

Это эффективный метод: обычно перемещающий конструктор копирует поля первого объекта во второй и как-то "опустошает" первый. Лишние ресурсы не нужны. Если компилятору доступен весь код и если в классе есть перемещающий конструктор, компилятор может превратить этот код в один вызов `memmove`:

```
for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
    new(&array(i + 1)) object_t(std::move(array(i)));
    array(i).~object_t();
}
```

### Копирующий конструктор

Это расточительный метод: для всех объектов создаются копии, оригинальные объекты уничтожаются:

```
for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
    new(&array(i + 1)) object_t(array(i));
    array(i).~object_t();
}
```

### Перемещающий оператор присваивания

По эффективности одинаков с перемещающим конструктором, если перемещающее присваивание определено в `object_t`:

```
new(&array(n - 1)) object_t;
for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
    array(i + 1) = std::move(array(i));
}
array(0).~object_t();
```

### Копирующий оператор присваивания

По эффективности одинаков с копирующим конструктором:

```
new(&array(n - 1)) object_t;
for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
    array(i + 1) = array(i);
}
array(0).~object_t();
```

### swap

Почти так же быстро как и перемещающий конструктор если класс определяет `swap`. Компилятору будет тяжело, но есть шанс что будет использован `memmove`:

```
new(&array(n - 1)) object_t;
for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
    swap(array(i + 1), array(i));
}
array(0).~object_t();
```

### Класс `object_t`

Вам понадобится этот класс чтобы отладить код выше. Может случится что в классе нет перемещающего конструктора, тогда компилятор молча использует копирующий, что радикально замедлит программу. Всякий раз тестируйте и проверяйте что код работает как ожидается.

Те методы, которые обычно реализуются без использования дополнительных ресурсов помечены `noexcept`. Это перемещающий конструктор, перемещающий оператор присваивания и `swap`. Используйте их если хотите двигать объекты в памяти действительно быстро:

```
struct object_t {
    object_t() : v(0) {
        std::cout << static_cast<void *>(this) << "()\n";
    }
    object_t(int v) : v(v) {
        std::cout << static_cast<void *>(this) << '(' << v << ")\n";
    }
    object_t(const object_t &other) : v(other.v) {
        std::cout << "copy " << static_cast<void *>(this) << '(' << static_cast<const void *>(&other) << ")\n";
    }
    object_t(object_t &&other) noexcept : v(other.v) {
        std::cout << "move " << static_cast<void *>(this) << '(' << static_cast<const void *>(&other) << ")\n";
    }
    void operator =(const object_t &other) {
        std::cout << "copy = " << static_cast<void *>(this) << '(' << static_cast<const void *>(&other) << ")\n";
        v = other.v;
    }
    void operator =(object_t &&other) noexcept {
        std::cout << "move = " << static_cast<void *>(this) << '(' << static_cast<const void *>(&other) << ")\n";
        v = other.v;
    }
    friend void swap(object_t &one, object_t &other) noexcept {
        std::cout << "swap(" << static_cast<void *>(&one) << ", " << static_cast<const void *>(&other) << ")\n";
        std::swap(one.v, other.v);
    }
    ~object_t() {
        std::cout << '~' << static_cast<void *>(this) << "()\n";
    }
    int v;
};
```

Comment: а при использовании move что фактически происходит с объектами? Они реально перемещаются или как? И почему компилятор может подставить туда memove если копирования может быть нетривиальным, а значит memmove нельзя?

Comment: На уровне процессора перемещения не бывает. Только копирование. Обычный перемещающий конструктор копирует поля из первого объекта во второй, затем "обнуляет" первый объект. Компилятор подставить `memmove` только если докажет что это безопасно. Скажем у вас в объекте есть поле строка. Она поддерживает перемещающее копирование. Причём это копирование такое: все байты копируются, первый объект обнуляется. Компилятор имеет доступ к  этому коду и может доказать что `memmove` сделает тоже самое. Тогда он впишет memmove, иначе не станет.

Comment: а если копирование/перемещение необычное, то memmove подставлен не будет? И как понять, когда компилятор поступит умно, а когда сделает влоб в других ситуациях, не обязательно связанных с копированием, а с чем угодно?

Comment: Если копирование необычное, то подстановки не будет. Качество оптимизации можно проверить проверив получающийся машинный код.

Comment: Хорошо, а тогда в чем разница между перемещающим и копирующим, если и там и там у вас вызывается деструктор старого элемента, а новый просто копирует поля старого? Или что имелось в виду под "обнулением"? А разве сам деструктор тогда не должен вызваться прям в самом перемещающем конструкторе?

Comment: Копирующий создаёт копию. Если был массив на гигабайт, нужен будет дополнительный гигабайт для копии. Перемещающий не делает копий ресурсов. Например, он копирует указатели и обнуляет (присваивает `nullptr`) их в исходном объекте. Деструктор в перемещающем конструкторе вызывать нельзя - правила языка не позволяют. Деструктор вызвать необходимо - нельзя конструировать поверх уже существующего объекта.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139832/discussion-between-supreme-machine-and-stanislav-volodarskiy).

Comment: Надо бы для `buffer` запросить дополнительное выравнивание: `alignas(object_t) unsigned char buffer[sizeof(object_t) * n];`. И, к сожалению, похоже что применение к указателю `array` арифметики указателей (`array[i]`) вызывает неопределённое поведение. Это вызвано тем, что тип объекта, на который указывает указатель `array` не совпадает с фактическим типом элементов массива `buffer`. См. [expr.add / 6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#6).

Comment: @wololo, так будет работать? `object_t *array = static_cast<object_t *>(::operator new(sizeof(object_t) * n));`

Comment: @wololo, заменил указатель на лямбду. Посмотрите на предмет UB. Если способ использовать нотацию `array[...]` без UB?

Comment: Да, вариант с лямбдой на мой взгляд UB не вызывает. Вариант с `operator new` UB вызывает. Это [относительно известный](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53451770) дефект стандарта. Но я напрасно раскритиковал ваш ответ, т.к. судя по всему, в C++20 данный дефект был исправлен. Если я правильно понял, идея следующая. Сишные функции распределения памяти, `operator new` и даже объявление массива из элементов типа `char`, `unsigned char`, `std::byte` неявным образом создают всевозможные массивы разных типов в подлежащем куске памяти. Что разрешает каст указателя в нужный тип и последующую арифметику.

Comment: См. [intro.memory/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#10).

Comment: @wololo, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Использовать другой класс массивов, например `std::deque<myobject>`. Данный класс реализует добавление и изымание объектов сначала и с конца без переноса данных в памяти. Чтобы перенести на позицию вправо, нужно всего-лишь добавить один элемент в начало.

```
std::deque<myobject> deq ;
myobject first ;
deq . push_front ( first ) ;
```

Comment: но он медленнее чем vector и требует место под указатели

Comment: `vector` - не решает вопрос. Он иногда переносит объекты. @SupremeMachine Есть ещё жёсткий вариант со списками `list`. Но оптимальный, я думаю это `deque`. Он обычно устроен как вектор векторов.

Comment: [What is std::deque and how deque works internally.](https://thispointer.com/what-is-stddeque-and-how-deque-works-internally/)

Comment: я знаю как работает deque,это просто связный список, но он медленный и занимает больше места( А мне нужно обычный массив двигать по аналогии с настоящим std vector